# Don't show repeated results in SQL query using INNER JOIN

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot

This is my current query:

```
SELECT e.*, j.application_date
FROM employee e JOIN job_application j ON e.Id=j.employeeId
WHERE j.status IN ('test1', 'test2')
ORDER BY j.application_date DESC
```

I am doing a JOIN with two tables, but I need not to show duplicate data using the e.Id as column to filter the duplicates.

Also, it must be sorted by column j.application_date to be able to receive the most recent

**UPDATE 1**

I have used the `DISTINCT` tag behind the `SELECT`, but it doesn't work because the rows are not exactly the same, that's why it doesn't work.

I don't know how to make it give me unique rows considering a single column (e.Id or j.employeeId)

**UPDATE 2**

If I have these 2 tables:

*employee table*

```
 Id        |  FirstName   | LastName      |  YearOfBirth
--------------------------------------------------------
  0        |  Thomas      | Smith         |   1977
  1        |  Peter       | Edison        |   1969
  2        |  Albon       | Boeraner      |   1995
  3        |  Mary        | Caters        |   1982
```

*job_application table*

```
 Id        |  employeeId  | application_date  | address    | status
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  0        |  1           |   2018-05-14      | address 1  | test1
  1        |  1           |   2018-02-19      | address 2  | test3
  2        |  1           |   2019-08-27      | address 3  | test2
  3        |  3           |   2019-11-16      | address 4  | test1
```

I need to show for the employee = 1 only the row that the application_date = 2019-08-27, and discard the other (application_date = 2018-05-14)

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
select e2.* , T2.Mapplication_date
from (select e.Id, max(j.application_date ) as Mapplication_date 
  FROM employee e JOIN job_application j ON e.Id=j.employeeId
    group by e.Id ) as T2
JOIN employee e2 ON e2.Id= T2.Id
```

Comment: I have used the "DISTINCT" tag behind the SELECT, but it doesn't work because the rows are not exactly the same, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know how to make it give me unique rows considering a single column (e.Id or j.employeeId)

Comment: can you add some of your data and your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
SELECT e.*, j.application_date
FROM employee e CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) j.*
      FROM job_application j 
      WHERE j.employeeId = e.id AND
            j.status IN ('test1', 'test2')
      ORDER BY j.application_date DESC
     ) j;
```

You are only looking for one column, so a correlated subquery would also work:

```
SELECT e.*, 
       (SELECT TOP (1) j.application_date
        FROM job_application j 
        WHERE j.employeeId = e.id AND
              j.status IN ('test1', 'test2')
        ORDER BY j.application_date DESC
       ) as application_date
FROM employee e;
```

The version using `apply` allows you to return more columns if you like.  And, this version also returns all employees, not just those with matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to number each application for employee by its date using row_number. So you can join just the last application (number = 1)

```
with last_application as (
  select employeeId,  application_date,
         row_number() over (partition by employeeId order by application_date desc) as num
  from job_application
  where status IN ('test1', 'test2')
)
select e.*, j.application_date
from employee
     inner join last_application j on j.employee_id = e.Id and j.num = 1
```